# How to store aggregated data in kdb+

Tags: kdb

I've faced with an architecture issue: what strategy should I choose to store aggregated data.

I know that in some Time Series DBs, like **RRDTools**, it is OK to have several db layers to store 1H,1W,1M,1Y aggregated data.

Is it a normal practice to use the same strategy for **kdb+**: to have several HDBs with date/month/year/int(for week and other) partitions? (with a rule on Gateway how to those an appropriate source.)

As an alternative I have in mind to store all data in a single HDB in tables like tablename**agg**. But it looks not so smooth like several HDBs to me.

What points should I take into account for a decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give a general answer as requirements are different for everyone but I can say in my experience that the normal practice is to have a single date-partitioned HDB as this can accommodate the widest range of historical datasets. In terms of increasing granularity of aggregation:

1. Full tick data - works best as date-partitioned with `p# on sym
2. Minutely aggregated data - still works well as date-partitioned with `p# on either sym or minute, `g# on either minute or sym
3. Hourly aggregated data - could be either date-partitioned or splayed depending on volume. Again you can have some combination of attributes on the sym and/or the aggregated time unit (in this case hour)
4. Weekly aggregated data - given how much this would compress the data you're now likely looking at a splayed table in this date-partitioned database. Use attributes as above.
5. Monthly/Yearly aggregated data - certainly could be splayed and possibly even flat given how small these tables would be. Attributes almost unnecessary in the flat case.

Maintaining many different HDBs with different partition styles would seem like overkill to me. But again it all depends on the situation and the volumes of data involved and in the expected usage pattern of the data.